# SQL AVG with Conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, average

I try to fix an SQL i did Earlier and have a problem while doing that.
I have  an Huge SQL witch Calculate SUM Fields for a Report.

ATM The SQL Counts Every Vehicle, even when its a Electro Car.

```
 CASE
          WHEN AVG(mov.TOTALCONSUMPTION)   >0
          AND AVG((moving.TOTALTIME)) >0
          THEN ROUND(AVG(mov.TOTALCONSUMPTION) / (AVG(mov.TOTALTIME)/3600), 4)
          ELSE 0
        END ConsumptionPerHour,
```

I need the Condition `Where vehicle.energysource = 0` in my sql,
I try to build it in but allways get the err. "not a GROUP BY expression"

```
 CASE
          WHEN AVG(mov.TOTALCONSUMPTION)   >0
          AND AVG((moving.TOTALTIME)) >0
          AND vehicle.ENERGYSOURCE= 0 
          THEN ROUND(AVG(mov.TOTALCONSUMPTION) / (AVG(mov.TOTALTIME)/3600), 4)
          ELSE 0
        END ConsumptionPerHour,
```

I know what the Error Mean but i have no Idear how to fix this.
Anyone have a Idear how i can solve this Problem?

(Btw its Oracle sql developer if that is helpfull)

Edit:

My Exact problem is that i cant put it in the Where part becouse my SQL have to Calculate some things with Electro Cars too like The driven Killometers Ect.

I have the Fuel Problem becouse i want to calculate the avg.
Lets say Car 1 is a Electro Car and Car to a Diesel Car.

The 1 one have a Consumption of 0(becouse Electric car) and the 2. one of 20.

My SQL now Calculate Sum of Consumption (Car 1+Car2  = 20) / amount of Cars:
Thats make a Avg Consumption of 10.

But i only need the Avg Consumption of all cars who are not electric cars.

Maybe a noob Question but im a Trainee and alone in the Office, so sorry if thats an Easy or bad explained question.

Comment: You say you need `Where vehicle.energysource = 0`, but in your 2nd query you added `AND vd.FUEL = 0 `. What's the connection? Like scaisEdge said, we need your whole query.

Comment: Im sorry i Change the name Fuel to energysource in the first SQL for better understanding. its the same.

Comment: Im sorry i forget to write that,  My SQL have to do some things with Electric cars too like calculate Killometers ect. Give me a second i Edit my post

Comment: Sounds like you want a conditional avg then, something like `AVG(case when vehicle.energysource = 0 then mov.TOTALCONSUMPTION end)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found a Solution, i simple created a Sub-Select and filter here if

```
vd.fuel = 0
```

Anyways, Thanks for Help.